# Problems with navbar dropdowns

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, href

I'm new to a web development. I am trying to create a navbar for my website. I took this script from bootstrap. I would like your advice on what href I should include in the line 2. I know what to put in the hrefs below that but I don't know what to include in the first one. I would like to click on the `Lists` and get a choice Action Another and Something else.

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="what link to put here?" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Lists
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Lists
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code is same except for the `<a>` tag. You don't have to include the **href** in it. Instead, just change the `data-bs-toggle` to `data-toggle`.